# Babel/webpack dependencies

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a private library I've converted to using es6 and webpack. How do I include this library in a way that I can import the entire source tree?

The library looks like this:

## portedlibrary

```
src/dir1/Class1.js
src/dir1/Class2.js
```

And my application looks like this:

## Application

```
src/app.js
src/app2.js
node_modules/portedlib/src/dir1/Class1.js
node_modules/portedlib/src/dir1/Class2.js
```

For internal imports, I can use relative pathing: `import {app2} from './app2`
For library imports, I import a single file: `import moment from 'moment'`

How do I import individual classes from `portedlibrary`?

When I try to import a class via `import {Class1} from 'portedlib'` I get the following error:
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'portedlibrary' in ...`

Comment: You can `import Class1 from 'portedlib/src/dir1/Class1';`, is what what you're looking for?

Comment: @loganfsmyth, that would also work! I'd post that as an snwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-export each of the default exports as a named export in another file (e.g. `index.js` so you can reference the lib by its name):

```
// node_modules/portedlib/index.js
export { default as Class1 } from './src/dir1/Class1'
export { default as Class2 } from './src/dir1/Class2'
```

And then import them:

```
import { Class1, Class2 } from 'portedlib'
```

Comment: Is there a tool to manually create this global export from a source tree? Or do I just need to manually enumerate all exports?